# Illustration of triangular number T(n) suggests isosceles?

Tags: real-analysis

A triangular number T(n) = 1+2+...+n can be visualized as a triangle of dots. Judging by such an illustration, T(n) appears to be an isosceles triangle with base = height = n, yet this is not so, as T(n) = n(n+1)/2. I know that a second triangle adjoins with the original to form a rectangle, adding a "column", but why is this necessary to determine the base of the triangle when it seems already complete? Is the illustration of the triangle with b=h somehow wrong?

Comment: $T(n)$ is just a collection of dots, you can arrange them to form a triangle in many ways.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Good observation! In fact, it **is** an isosceles-like arrangement of dots with base $=$ height $=n$, but it is not actually a triangle, so the usual geometric area formula isn't going to do the job for us in this case. In particular, when we put together two congruent isosceles right triangles, we can "glue" the hypotenuses together (without losing any area) to get a square. However, when we put together two such arrangements of dots, we get an $n+1$ by $n$ rectangle instead, as we cannot combine the "hypotenuses" without losing dots.

Answer (score 1):

It has to do with the fact that the visualization is **discrete**. The "hypotenuse" of the isosceles right triangle is not really a straight line, but a jagged zigzag of unit squares. As $n \to \infty$, this complication becomes less noticeable and the area formula of $n^2/2$ starts to look more like the actual formula of $n(n+1)/2$.

Answer (score 1):

Each $T(n)$ enumerates (exactly) the points with integer coordinates in the isosceles right triangle with vertices $(1,1)$, $(1,n)$ and $(n,1)$ (boundary included).